# Magento2 Catalog Search index process unknown error: | elasticsuite

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I've install elasticsuite but during reindex  Catalog Search I get issue. Any solution?

```
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":
[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"in  
                            dex [magento2_pl_catalog_product_20210118_123614/sSFlWyPJS2mhmE4WCG7T_Q] already                               exists","index_uuid":"sSFlWyPJS2mhmE4WCG7T_Q","index":"magento2_pl_catalog_prod                              uct_20210118_123614"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"inde                              x [magento2_pl_catalog_product_20210118_123614/sSFlWyPJS2mhmE4WCG7T_Q] already e                              xists","index_uuid":"sSFlWyPJS2mhmE4WCG7T_Q","index":"magento2_pl_catalog_produc                              t_20210118_123614"},"status":400}
    ElasticSuite Category Indexing index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your ElasticSearch version installed and the one that's selected in your admin panel, it probably isn't the same selected in the Magento admin panel.

[image: Magento 2 ElasticSearch Admin panel]

This command will help you to check the version, you might change the host.

```
curl http://elasticsearch:9200
```

```
{
  "name" : "jPBGI6O",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "eR6UbtkgSJC8zO-J6jSF2A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2018-12-17T21:17:40.758843Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

[image: Magento 2 ElasticSearch]